# Check if a given ostream object has been written to

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream

Can I query an `ostream` object about whether or not it has been written to? For an `ostringstream`, one could use

```
if(!myOssObject.str().empty())
```

What about the general case, e.g. an `ofstream` or `cout` or `cerr`?

Comment: Something like stream.rdbuf()->[in_avail()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/in_avail) ?

Comment: @TomKnapen `std::streambuf::in_avail` shouldn't be affected by output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general No.

You can find out how many char (or something else) is written before flushing (sending out the buffered data) by [`tellp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/tellp):

> Returns the output position indicator of the current associated
>   streambuf object.

```
cout << "123";

if (cout.tellp() > 0)
{
    // There is some data written
}
```

After flushing, these output streams will *forget* what they've written but the last state flags.

If the output device is a real-time and doesn't buffer anything, `tellp` can't help.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible, but only if you can get your hands on the stream
beforehand.  The only generally guaranteed solution is to insert
a filtering streambuf, which keeps track of the number of
characters output:

```
class CountOutput : public std::streambuf
{
    std::streambuf* myDest;
    std::ostream*   myOwner;
    int myCharCount;    //  But a larger type might be necessary

protected:
    virtual int overflow( int ch )
    {
        ++ myCharCount;
        return myDest->sputc( ch );
    }

public:
    CountOutput( std::streambuf* dest )
        : myDest( dest )
        , myOwner( nullptr )
        , myCharCount( 0 )
    {
    }
    CountOutput( std::ostream& dest )
        : myDest( dest.rdbuf() )
        , myOwner( &dest )
        , myCharCount( 0 )
    {
        myOwner->rdbuf( this );
    }
    ~CountOutput()
    {
        if ( myOwner != nullptr ) {
            myOwner.rdbuf( myDest );
        }
    }

    int count() const
    {
        return myCount;
    }
};
```

As usual, this can be used with just about any `std::ostream`:

```
CountOutput counter( someOStream );
//  output counted here...
int outputCount = counter.count();
```

When it goes out of scope, it will restore the original state of
the stream.

Comment: If you are willing to spend the time learning it, Boost.Iostreams has a [counter class](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) which does precisely that; counts lines and characters, and then forwards it.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that one, but I do know that it supports my filtering streambuf technique in general.